# Idiom for setting a variable in top-level scope

Tags: cmake, idioms, cmake-language, cmake-scopes

I have a `CMakeLists.txt`  which sometimes serves as a project top-level list file and is sometimes used with `add_subdirectory()`.

Now, for reasons, this file needs to set a variable in the top-level scope. The way I achieve this right now is:

```
if (PROJECT_IS_TOP_LEVEL)
    set(FOO "bar")
else()
    set(FOO "bar" PARENT_SCOPE)
endif()
```

but this is verbose and redundant. What would be a better idiom for doing this?